# submithandler of Jquery validation plugin not working for ajax submit bootstrap 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development, especially jquery and bootstrap. I am trying to use jquery validation plugin to validate my forms. Everything works fine in normal form submits, whereas if I am trying to submit the form through ajax, it doesn't seem to work at all. All validations are simply ignored.

**HTML**

```
<form class="ajaxForm"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_firstname" required data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Please enter your First name" data-rule-names="true" data-msg-names="Please enter alphabets only"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.submit', function() {
            try {
                var form, data, url, type, elem_id, a_mode, e_mode, pieces;
                form = $(this).closest('form.ajaxFrom');

                data = form.serialize();

                form.validate({
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'post.php',
                            data: data,
                            beforeSend: function() {

                            },
                            success: function(html) {
                                alert('success');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't want to use form.submit() because it refreshes the page and kinda spoils the whole point of me using ajax here. I do not want to refresh or redirect the page.

Comment: whether the form are dynamically created?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0hxL0qzr/2/

Comment: `form = $(this).closest('form.ajaxFrom');` != `form = $(this).closest('form.ajaxForm');`

Comment: why are you catching the `click` event of the submit button ? Wouldn't  the `submit` event of the `form` be better suited for that purpose

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0hxL0qzr/2/

Comment: @dvhh one reason to do so is if the forms are created dynamically and you want to initialize the plugin lazy

Comment: @ArunPJohny Even then you could still assign the event handler the same way

Comment: @dvhh then event handler is using event delegation

Comment: @Arun P Johny: yeah the form is generated dynamically using .load() function. On click of one button, .load() generates this form and on click of save button I wanna access few variables to send as data for the form and also do few more stuff like hide/show/remove something....so I wanted to capture the click event

Comment: @ChandanDNadig did you change the class name and test

Comment: @Arjun P Johny: your fiddle looks great man, I'm gonna try it as soon as I reach home and update what happened. Thank you. P.S. will this work for dynamically generated form !!!!

Comment: Arjun P Johny:  I'm out on some important work, can check it only in the evening. Hey and one more request, can I contact you by any other means (like email/Facebook/google+) !! I'm not able to find answers for the problems I am facing and although SO has been really useful, it takes almost 3-4 days for me to solve trivial issues. In case you agree, please drop me a mail. This is my email id : chandan.nadig@gmail.com... Thank you